# Discord.py trying to get the arriving messages from X GUILD and Y CHANNEL which I do not own through a bot

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to get the arriving messages from X guild and Y channel that i do not own in Discord through a bot.
Here's the current code:

```
import discord
import asyncio

class MyClient(discord.Client):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # create the background task and run it in the background
    self.bg_task = self.loop.create_task(self.my_background_task())

async def on_ready(self):
    print('Logged in as')
    print(self.user.name)
    print(self.user.id)
    print('------')

async def my_background_task(self):
    await self.wait_until_ready()
    msg = await self.get_channel(818581199751479299).history(limit=1).flatten()
    msg = msg[0]
    print(msg)
    await self.close() # close client once we are done

client = MyClient()
client.run('BOT_TOKEN')
```

At the moment I've this code but my_background_task never executes, so what should i do to solve this issue?
The thing I want to do is pretty simple but I can't solve it alone with my current knowledge.

Also, when I try to execute the line:

```
msg = await self.get_channel(818581199751479299).history(limit=1).flatten()
```

it says me that history attribute is not found.

Well, let's see if I can solve all of this, thank you all for your help :)

Comment: Can we have the full traceback please?

Comment: Another thing, it seems you are asking two unrelated questions in the same post. I suggest making multiple questions for these two seperate problems.